# syntaxnet bazel test failed

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet

I ran `bazel test syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...` and it gave me this output:

```
FAIL: //syntaxnet:parser_trainer_test (see /home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_rushat/cc4d67663fbe887a603385d628fdf383/syntaxnet/bazel-out/local-opt/testlogs/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test/test.log).
INFO: Elapsed time: 2179.396s, Critical Path: 1623.00s
//syntaxnet:arc_standard_transitions_test                                PASSED in 0.7s
//syntaxnet:beam_reader_ops_test                                         PASSED in 24.1s
//syntaxnet:graph_builder_test                                           PASSED in 14.6s
//syntaxnet:lexicon_builder_test                                         PASSED in 6.1s
//syntaxnet:parser_features_test                                         PASSED in 5.8s
//syntaxnet:reader_ops_test                                              PASSED in 9.4s
//syntaxnet:sentence_features_test                                       PASSED in 0.2s
//syntaxnet:shared_store_test                                            PASSED in 41.7s
//syntaxnet:tagger_transitions_test                                      PASSED in 5.2s
//syntaxnet:text_formats_test                                            PASSED in 6.1s
//util/utf8:unicodetext_unittest                                         PASSED in 0.4s
//syntaxnet:parser_trainer_test                                          FAILED in 0.5s
  /home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/cc4d67663fbe887a603385d628fdf383/syntaxnet/bazel-out/local-opt/testlogs/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test/test.log

Executed 12 out of 12 tests: 11 tests pass and 1 fails locally.
There were tests whose specified size is too big. Use the --test_verbose_timeout_warnings command line option to see which ones these are.
```

If you want the output of `--test_verbose_timeout_warnings`, please ask.

Test.log output is below because Stackoverflow tells me I have too much code in my post :/

Thanks!

---

test.log output:

```
exec ${PAGER:-/usr/bin/less} "$0" || exit 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ BINDIR=/home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/cc4d67663fbe887a603385d628fdf383/syntaxnet/bazel-out/local-opt/bin/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test.runfiles/syntaxnet
+ CONTEXT=/home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/cc4d67663fbe887a603385d628fdf383/syntaxnet/bazel-out/local-opt/bin/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test.runfiles/syntaxnet/testdata/context.pbtxt
+ TMP_DIR=/tmp/syntaxnet-output
+ mkdir -p /tmp/syntaxnet-output
+ sed s=OUTPATH=/tmp/syntaxnet-output=
+ sed s=SRCDIR=/home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/cc4d67663fbe887a603385d628fdf383/syntaxnet/bazel-out/local-opt/bin/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test.runfiles= /home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/cc4d67663fbe887a603385d628fdf383/syntaxnet/bazel-out/local-opt/bin/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test.runfiles/syntaxnet/testdata/context.pbtxt
sed: can't read /home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/cc4d67663fbe887a603385d628fdf383/syntaxnet/bazel-out/local-opt/bin/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test.runfiles/syntaxnet/testdata/context.pbtxt: No such file or directory
+ PARAMS=128-0.08-3600-0.9-0
+ /home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/cc4d67663fbe887a603385d628fdf383/syntaxnet/bazel-out/local-opt/bin/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test.runfiles/syntaxnet/parser_trainer --arg_prefix=brain_parser --batch_size=32 --compute_lexicon --decay_steps=3600 --graph_builder=greedy --hidden_layer_sizes=128 --learning_rate=0.08 --momentum=0.9 --output_path=/tmp/syntaxnet-output --task_context=/tmp/syntaxnet-output/context --training_corpus=training-corpus --tuning_corpus=tuning-corpus --params=128-0.08-3600-0.9-0 --num_epochs=12 --report_every=100 --checkpoint_every=1000 --logtostderr
syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test: line 36: /home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/cc4d67663fbe887a603385d628fdf383/syntaxnet/bazel-out/local-opt/bin/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test.runfiles/syntaxnet/parser_trainer: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the correct bazel version installed for syntaxnet to compile. I had the latest build and it didn;t work. So I removed it by deleting the folder

```
rm -fr .cache/bazel
```

and then reinstalled the correct version bazel==0.2.2b by downloading the correct installer from the [download page](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases)

and running it on my machine

```
sudo chmod +x bazel-version.sh
./bazel-version.sh --user
```

Comment: @Rainbowteddycoderguy check the following [links1](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/962) [links2](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/962) `rm ~/.bazel ~/.bazelrc`

Comment: @Rainbowteddycoderguy What version did you have earlier ? 0.2.3

Comment: Yes i had 0.2.3. I came by the solution on my thread in github.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the syntaxnet test, it's looking for the wrong path.  It needs the following patch:

```
diff --git a/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test.sh b/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test.sh
index ba2a6e7..977c89c 100755
--- a/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test.sh
+++ b/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test.sh
@@ -22,7 +22,7 @@

 set -eux

-BINDIR=$TEST_SRCDIR/syntaxnet
+BINDIR=$TEST_SRCDIR/$TEST_WORKSPACE/syntaxnet
 CONTEXT=$BINDIR/testdata/context.pbtxt
 TMP_DIR=/tmp/syntaxnet-output
```

Comment: where do i apply this patch and how?

Comment: Open up the file syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test.sh and change line 25 to `BINDIR=$TEST_SRCDIR/$TEST_WORKSPACE/syntaxnet`.